# $E=mc^2$ and particles

Tags: fermions

This is a simple question.  Does the Energy create both Fermion and Boson particles ? or just only the Fermion particles?

Comment: All particles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $$E=mc^2,$$ or more generally $$E^2=(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2,$$ is valid for any particle. More info on this energy-momentum relation can be found on its [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation). I suppose one can take the lack of "fermion" or "boson" on this page as indication of its general applicability.

Answer (score 0):

E=mc^2 applie to all particles.  The differences in masses is the basis of nuclear and even chemical energy.  For example, a H atom is lighter than a proton and electron by the energy of ionisation.